# URLs of categories and tags are not slugs

Tags: pelican

When I write blog entries and add a category or tags then the pages for categories and tags are generated properly. But the links to this pages don't use the slug. They use the title of the page.
i.e. I have a tag called 'C++'. The page for that tag is properly generated at {...}/tag/c.html but the link in the blog post points to {...}/tag/C++.html

Is this a bug in Pelican? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is something in the pelican template. I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: I had to make some minor changes in the templates: `article.category` to `article.category.slug` and `tag` to `tag.slug`